Remove Meeting from Calendar
I have a large number of users who have a meeting in their calendar that lasts every month for 10 years. I need to access each user's calendar to make sure that this meeting is no longer there, or if it is, to display who has it so I can go in and delete it. I tried using Get-MgUserEvent, but it only shows common meetings.
$startDate = "2024-04-03T00:00:00Z" 
$endDate = "2024-04-05T23:59:59Z"  

    Get-MgUserEvent -UserId "Test-user1@test1.pl" -Filter "start/dateTime ge '$startDate' and start/dateTime le '$endDate'"

any help? :(

Instead of using Get-MgUserEvent you should use Get-MgUserCalendarView this will do a calendar expansion meaning that it will expand any recurring events during the time period you specify while Get-MgUserEvent doesn't do an expansion so will exclude any recurring events and return the master instances. eg
 Get-MgUserCalendarView -UserId "Test-user1@test1.pl" -StartDateTime $startDate -EndDateTime $endDate

If the subject of the event is unique the just doing a filter on that would probably be a better approach as you can the check for the master instance and delete that eg
Get-MgUserEvent -UserId "Test-user1@test1.pl" -Filter "Subject eq 'Meeting Subject'"

